# Parameter 0 of constructor in [] required a bean of type [] that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

**Error**: Parameter 0 of constructor in com.tw.api.service.impl.BookServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.tw.api.repository.BookRepository' that could not be found.

**Exception**: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController' defined in file [/Users/rashdul.ehasan/Projects/boot-camp/api/target/classes/com/tw/api/controller/BookController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/rashdul.ehasan/Projects/boot-camp/api/target/classes/com/tw/api/service/impl/BookServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tw.api.repository.BookRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations

Any idea on how to fix this?

I have excluded the default auto configuration...

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ApiApplication {
```

I have written a factory bean class for mongo but it does not seem to reach there.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring", name = "db.dialect", havingValue = "mongo", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = ApiMongoRepositoryFactoryBean.class,
        basePackages = "com.tw.api.repository")
public class ApiMongoRepositoryConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String uri;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiMongoRepositoryConfig.class);

    public ApiMongoRepositoryConfig() {
        LOGGER.info("Repository Configuration: " + ApiMongoRepositoryConfig.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(uri));
    }
}
```

Packages:

```
BookController: package com.tw.api.controller;
BookService: package com.tw.api.service;
BookServiceImpl: package com.tw.api.service.impl;
BookRepository: package com.tw.api.repository;

ApiMongoRepository: package com.tw.api.repository.base;
ApiMongoRepositoryConfig: package com.tw.api.config;
ApiMongoRepositoryFactoryBean: package com.tw.api.helper;

ApiApplication: package com.tw.api;
```

**Here is the link to the code base,** https://github.com/er310/boot-camp/tree/master/api

Comment: Where is the `BookServiceImpl`? Where is the `BookRepository`? Please post the full exception.

Comment: @JensSchauder - I have edited the above. Please have a look and you can find the code base here, https://github.com/er310/boot-camp/tree/master/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `Book` class marked as a JPA entity:

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Book extends AbstractEntity {
```

But you are only creating Mong repositories with `@EnableMongoRepositories`.

You need to make up your mind if you want to use MongoDb with Spring Data Mongo or a relational database with JPA + Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I realised that is an issue but I wanted to use the entity for both Mongo & Jpa... I understand the Table is for Jpa and Document for Mongo.... Is there any that I can use for both NonSQL and SQL?

I want to use Mongo or Jpa by switching config one to another by @ConditionalOnProperty. This is why I want to use same entity for both types so that it can be switched one to another.

Comment: That is a completely different question. Please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I assume that this Entity or Document issue is not related to the dependency error mentioned in the original! I tried using ComponentScan but could not get it working yet.

Comment: I found the answer of using JPA and Mongo with one model..
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules

Comment: I needed to add both annotations (@Entity & @Document) in the entity model, then manage the config for jpa & mongo